# Syntax error using javascript when assigning

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, taglib

i am trying to assign the following to a string to append.

`<table id="<%=tableName%>" width="70%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">`

but when i try:

```
var str = "<table id="<%=tableName%>" width="70%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">"
```

I get a syntax error. How do I solve the problem of the double quotation inside a string? i actually do need it because of how jsp taglibs work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a quote issue. The double quotes for your string are colliding with the double quotes in your attributes in your string.

```
var str = "<table id="<%=tableName%>" width="70%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">"
```

should be

```
var str = '<table id="<%=tableName%>" width="70%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">'
```

Answer (score 2):

You either need to escape the double quotes in your string (as you are using double quoted strings)

```
var str = "<table id=\"<%=tableName%>\" width=\"70%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\">"
```

OR

user a single quoted string

```
var str = '<table id=\"<%=tableName%>\" width=\"70%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\">'
```